# SQL Server Convert DD/MM/YY to YYYY-DD-MM

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to do this in the INSERT SQL. Can anyone show me.

Thanks

--Mark

Comment: Is the date a datetime or (var)char?

Comment: Also should that be YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to insert a date into a table? If so, why does the format matter?

Comment: which country use yyyy-dd-mm format?

Comment: Looks a bit of an odd format to me..

Comment: What do you mean by INSERT SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
insert into TableName(DateColumn)
select convert(datetime,getDate(),103)
```

Comment: 103 isn't defined in 2K AFAIK, I get 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm'

Comment: You'll be damned if you can find a standard format that gives you `YYYY-DD-MM`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx so convert is no good.

Answer (score 3):

[complete list of date format, or close](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I follow entirely, but if you are taking a `datetime` of the form 'dd/mm/yy' and are trying to get it into a `varchar(10)` of the form `yyyy-dd-mm` then I think you'll need to convert to a varchar and then use `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to pull out the data you need:

```
declare @dt datetime 
select @dt = getdate() -- i.e. 04/09/2009

declare @str varchar(8)
select @str = convert(varchar(8),@dt,112)  --gives 20090904
select LEFT(@str,4) + '-' + RIGHT(@str,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@str,5,2) -- gives 2009-04-09
```

It isn't pretty, but it works!

Comment: I'd rather go for a more general date formatting function than hacking up the format on a case by case basis :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this custom date formatting function from http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

This allows you to format dates in anyway you want. However i'm not sure why you'd want a date in the format `YYYY-DD-MM` as this is rather non-standard.

```
————
– SQL datetime functions
– SQL Server date formats
– T-SQL convert dates
– Formatting dates sql server

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFormatDate (@Datetime DATETIME, @FormatMask VARCHAR(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StringDate VARCHAR(32)
    SET @StringDate = @FormatMask
    IF (CHARINDEX ('YYYY',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'YYYY',
                         DATENAME(YY, @Datetime))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('YY',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'YY',
                         RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, @Datetime),2))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('Month',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'Month',
                         DATENAME(MM, @Datetime))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('MON',@StringDate COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)>0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'MON',
                         LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime)),3))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('Mon',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'Mon',
                                     LEFT(DATENAME(MM, @Datetime),3))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('MM',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'MM',
                  RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)),2))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('M',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'M',
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM, @Datetime)))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('DD',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'DD',
                         RIGHT('0'+DATENAME(DD, @Datetime),2))

    IF (CHARINDEX ('D',@StringDate) > 0)
       SET @StringDate = REPLACE(@StringDate, 'D',
                                     DATENAME(DD, @Datetime))   

RETURN @StringDate
END
```

Then you can call this:
    `SELECT dbo.fnFormatDate (getdate(), 'YYYY-DD-MM')`

Comment: Hmm voting wars... fun games children... Please leave comments with any downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

We doesn't know whether `YY` in `DD/MM/YY` is in current century or previous century. For example, if `YY` is `15`, we doesn't know whether that is `1915` or `2015`. So the numbers between 0 and 15 will be treated as current century. If the current year is 2016, then the numbers between 0 and 16 will be treated as current century(its dynamic).

**EXAMPLE**

- When `YY` is `15`, then `YYYY` will be `2015`.
- When `YY` is `97`, then `YYYY` will be `1997`.

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @DATECOL VARCHAR(13) = '25/01/15'


SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(@DATECOL,2) BETWEEN 0 AND CAST(RIGHT(YEAR(GETDATE()),2)AS INT) 
THEN '20' + RIGHT(@DATECOL,2) ELSE '19' + RIGHT(@DATECOL,2) END
+ '-' + LEFT(@DATECOL,2) + '-' +  LEFT(RIGHT(@DATECOL,5),2)
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d70ef/1)**